# How to add profile picture for other users?

Tags: 2013, powershell

I want to add profile pictures for some of our users in SharePoint 2013. How can I do that? Maybe with Powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the link to bulk upload profile picture using Powershell.
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Bulk-Upload-and-Update-2c27437e

we have used this in one of our project. It may help you.

If you are running the script in a fresh SharePoint installation, make sure that User Photos library exist in your My Sites host and also that there is a folder in it called Profile Pictures. If no user has a profile picture most probably the folder is missing. You can create it manually or by uploading a profile picture for some account.

Comment: I tried this script but get the following error: `Unable to upload the picture for account: "MYDOMAIN\Myuser"
Updating Profile Photo Store....`

Comment: Now it works, I had a permission problem with the user running the script.

Comment: @jlai79: Glad to know that :)

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way to add profile pictures is to visit the other users profile and upload the picture the same way you do on your own profile.

You need to have be an administrator to do that. I don't know the exact permissions you need to have.